# Remove table row in jquery using table name

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

I am iterating through checked table rows and want to delete the current row if a certain argument is true but what I have so far deletes the wrong one. Any help appreciated. This is what I have.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { 
    if (this.checked == true) {
        var del_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');

        $.each(del_arr, function(index, value ) {
            if (value == del_id) {
                $('#spreadsheetstable tr:last').remove();
                console.log('Removing :'+  del_id +' And ' + value);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you share the html too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {

    var $tr =  $(this).closest('tr');

    var del_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');

    $.each(del_arr, function(index, value ) {

        if (value == del_id){
            $tr.remove();
            console.log('Removing :'+  del_id +' And ' + value);
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: The problem was you were using tr:last which means the last row on the table.  I updated the selector to only look at checked rows, and then established the row to delete at the same time (statement before) that you checked for the value of data-id on the row.  Return false (just in case you don't know) breaks the array search for the matching id.

Comment: No need to traverse `$(this).closest('tr')` twice, just replace the second call with `$tr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery DataTables it's better to remove row using DataTables API method [row().remove()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.remove%28%29) rather than manipulate DOM directly.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
   var $tr =  $(this).closest('tr');
   var del_id = $tr.attr('data-id');
   $.each(del_arr, function(index, value ) {
      if (value == del_id){
         $('#spreadsheetstable').DataTable().row($tr).remove().draw(false);

         console.log('Removing :'+  del_id +' And ' + value);
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: @Gyrocode.com i am trying to use that but it doesn't work? i can't figure out how to retrieve the instance of datatables.

Comment: @r3wt, use `$('#example').DataTable()` to get DataTables API instance, where `example` is your table ID.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com i never got it working that way using the new datatables. i was able to get `fnDeleteRow()` to work, but i could never use `.row().remove()`